# Embedding image's stored in private github repo into Markdown file

Tags: image, github, markdown, embed

I have a private GitHub repo (https://github.com/UserName/Images/....) in which i am storing images / screenshots for a project i am working on within an Azure workbook.

These workbooks within Azure are based on Markdown and i need to embed the images stored within this private repo.

I have attempted to use the following methods to embed these images:

```
![Private picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/Images/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png)

![Private picture](https://github.com/UserName/Images/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png?raw=true)
```

Opening the image in a new tab gives the image a token which works until this token expires / generating a token manually within my github account with full access just leads to a 404 error

```
![Private picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UserName/Images/Screenshot%202020-09-15%20at%2010.32.38.png?token=xxxxxxxx)
```

Does any one have any other suggestions / how i can generate a PAT that will allow an image stored in a private repo to be accessed via a browser?